# Is every element of Spin(4) an element of Spin(8)?

Tags: group-theory, clifford-algebras

My question is simple: I have an element of Spin(4) written in terms of $16\times 16$ matrices from a Clifford algebra $C\ell_{8,0}$. Does this imply that any such element is also an element of Spin(8)?

I understand that the other way around doesn't need to hold since there are things built in a 8-dimensional space that cannot be built using solely quantities from a 4-dimensional space. However, I'm not sure if every element of Spin(4) belongs to Spin(8) as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think so. The composite map Spin(4)->SO(4)->SO(8) lifts to a map Spin(4)->Spin(8) since Spin(4) is simply connected. Since the first map is 2-1, the second map is injective, and the universal cover is 2-1, it should be possible to show the resulting map is injective.

Comment: I don't think its possible to say anything without describing what representations you're using.